# Bound Mismatch with collections.sort

Tags: java, collections, comparable

I have a application that has a sqlite DB whos content is put into an arraylist and viewable through a list view. My issue is that I am unable to get the item in alphabetical order. I have implemented `Collections.sort()` but receive a Bound Mismatch error. any ideas

Error:

Bound mismatch: The generic method `sort(List<T>)` of type `Collections` is not applicable for the arguments `(ArrayList<LoginDetails>)`. The inferred type `LoginDetails` is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

```
private ListView loginList;
private Button webLogin;
private ListAdapter loginListAdapter;
private ArrayList<LoginDetails> loginArrayList;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_listview);


    loginList = (ListView)
    findViewById(R.id.loginlist);
    loginList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    webLogin = (Button)
    findViewById(R.id.button3);
    webLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

    loginArrayList = new ArrayList<LoginDetails>();
    loginListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, populateList());
    loginList.setAdapter(loginListAdapter);

    Collections.sort(loginArrayList ); //Bound mismatch error is here.
    }
```

LoginDetails:

```
public class LoginDetails {

private String sName;
private String wUrl;
private String uName;
private String pWord;

public String getsName() {
return sName;
}
public void setsName(String sName) {
this.sName = sName;
}

public String getwUrl() {
return wUrl;
}
public void setwUrl(String wUrl) {
this.wUrl = wUrl;
}

public String getuName() {
return uName;
}
public void setuName(String uName) {
this.uName = uName;
}
public String getpWord() {
return pWord;
}
public void setpWord(String pWord) {
this.pWord = pWord;
}

}
```

Comment: Does `LoginDetails` implement `Comparable`?

Comment: It would be useful if you add your class declaration for LoginDetails.

Comment: Che,the login Details class has been added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in the API doc, for `Collections.sort`:

> All elements in the list must implement the Comparable interface.

Make sure `LoginDetails` implements `Comparable`.

For example:

```
public class LoginDetails implements Comparable<LoginDetails>{
    //...        

    @Override
    public int compareTo(LoginDetails another) {
        return uName.compareTo(another.uName);
    }

    //...
```